# Is there a name for the exponential semiring of G-sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, type-theory, semiring

**Is there a name for the exponential semiring of G-sets?**

In an ordinary type system, the types are like sets.

It's possible to extend this analogy and get a $G$-type system where every type is acted on by a fixed group $G$ and these actions respect the type constructors $+, \times, \to$ and so on.

---

The Burnside semiring of a group $G$ looks a lot like a simple type system with products $ \times $ and coproducts $ + $.

[This lecture by Richard Borcherds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuQcj3GdayE&t=35s) contains a construction of the Burnside semiring and later the Burnside ring.

This can be thought of as similar to a type system. The $G$-sets, $A_1 \cdots A_n$ are the irreducible transitive actions of $G$ on finite sets. They are analogous to primitive types.

$A+B = \{ (S^+, 1, a, (A, B)) : a \in A \} \cup \{ (S^+, 2, b, (A, B)) : b \in B \}$ is like a coproduct.

$A \times B = \{ (S^\times, a, b, (A, B)) : a \in A \land b \in B \}$ is like a product.

The group action is defined as follows:

$$g \triangleright (S^+, 1, a, (A, B))) = (S^+, 1, g \triangleright a, (A, B))$$

$$g \triangleright (S^+, 2, b, (A, B)) = (S^+, 2, g \triangleright b, (A, B))$$

$$ g \triangleright (S^\times, a, b, (A, B)) = (S^\times, g \triangleright a, g \triangleright b, (A, B)) $$

We can get a version of the simply typed lambda calculus by adding in $A \to B$.

$$ g \triangleright (S^\to, \{ \cdots (a, b) \cdots \}, (A, B)) = (S^\to, \{ \cdots (g \triangleright a, g^{-1} \triangleright b) \cdots \}, (A, B)) $$

Or equivalently $g \triangleright \lambda x \mathop. f(x) \longrightarrow \lambda x \mathop. g \triangleright f(g^{-1} \triangleright x)$.

We can show that this definition of conjugation for a function makes sense by examining $f : A \times B \to C$ and $h : A \to B \to C$.

$$ g \triangleright (f : A \times B \to C) \\
g \triangleright (\lambda (a, b) \mathop. c(a, b)) \\
(\lambda (a, b) \mathop. g \triangleright c(g^{-1} \triangleright a, g^{-1} \triangleright b)))
$$

Which resembles

$$ g \triangleright ( h : A \to B \to C ) \\
g \triangleright (\lambda a \mathop. \lambda b \mathop. c(a, b)) \\
\lambda a \mathop. g \triangleright (\lambda b \mathop. c(g^{-1} \triangleright a, b) \\
\lambda a \mathop. \lambda b \mathop. g \triangleright c(g^{-1} \triangleright a, g^{-1} \triangleright b) $$

And also, conjugation treats the identity function correctly:

$$ g \triangleright \text{id} \\
g \triangleright (\lambda x \mathop. x) \\
(\lambda x \mathop. g \triangleright g^{-1} \triangleright x) \\
\lambda x \mathop. x $$

Comment: Why restrict your attention to the semiring structure? The *category* of $G$-sets is a cartesian closed category with finite coproducts, what is sometimes called a bicartesian closed category, and even a Grothendieck topos: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicartesian+closed+category, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topos